# How do i bind an "Entry Cell" to a custom object using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin

I have been playing with [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) for a short time so far, and i just stumbled into something i couldn't find the answer into their documentation.

I am building a fairly simple app that retrieves "User Data" (username, email, password and so forth) from a RESTfull API and populates a listview with some of the data (This is the point i am at the moment. It works).

The next step is to build a "Edit User" screen, which is invoked uppon selecting (tapping) a user on the Listview i currently have.

I have managed to build a simple view that is basically two [Entry Cells](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.EntryCell) showing the data of the user picked into the previous listview screen. That also works.

The problem is that, once i edit the data into the "Entry Cell" it has no reflection into the "User Model" that populated the "entry cell" in first place.

How do i bind those together?

**Code Sample:**

```
// Entry Cell of Username (Should be Binded)
        EntryCell ecUsername = new EntryCell()
        {
            Label       = "Username:",
            Placeholder = "username / login",
            Text        = _user.Username
        };

        // Entry Cell of Password (Should be Binded)
        EntryCell ecEmail  = new EntryCell ()
        {
            Label = "Email:",
            Placeholder = "user email",
            Text        = _user.Email
        };
```

**Some Screenshots:**
[image: ListView of Users]

Once i click into a user, its data gets rendered into the next screen.

[image: Edit Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but something like this should work:

```
EntryCell ec = new EntryCell ();
ec.BindingContext = _user;
ec.SetBinding (EntryCell.TextProperty, "Username");
```

Comment: What this _user? ViewModel?